# Use sparse matrix within some scipy functions

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use scipy build-in ConvexHull function on a large sparse matrix.

So far I did the following :

```py
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

    X = Y.toarray() #Y is sparse
    hull = ConvexHull(X)
```

But this approach is taking too long. Is there a way to pass the sparse matrix Y directly into the Convex Hull method ?

Comment: Did you profile the function? What takes time, converting the matrix to an array, or the convex hull calculation?

Comment: If `ConvexHull` does not say it accepts a sparse matrix, no.